# Eigen::eigen2_Transform3D and TF

Tags: ros, tf2, eigen3, transform-listener, stampedtransform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I am trying to use tf::TransformTFToEigen with a TF listener.

I have both eigen2 and eigen3 installed.

The error I get is "'eigen2_Transform3d' is not a member of Eigen".  I was assuming that including <tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h> would pull in any eigen dependencies, as that is what happens in tf_eigen.cpp.

Here is my code:

```
 #include <ros/ros.h>
 #include "std_msgs/String.h"
 #include "std_msgs/Float32.h"
 #include <tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h>
 #include <tf/transform_listener.h>

 int main(int argc, char** argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "openni_tracker_listener");

   ros::NodeHandle node;

   tf::TransformListener listener;

   Eigen::eigen2_Transform3d t;

   ros::Rate rate(10.0);

   while (node.ok()){

     tf::StampedTransform transform;

     try{
       listener.lookupTransform( "/right_hand", "/left_hand",  
                            ros::Time(0), transform);
       tf::TransformTFToEigen(transform,t);

     }catch (tf::TransformException ex){
       ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
     }
     ros::spinOnce();
     rate.sleep();
   }
   return 0;
 };
```

Thanks for the help!

Kel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29729/eigen::eigen2_transform3d-and-tf/) by [Kel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1972/kel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"eigen2_Transform3d" is an artifact of the Diamondback API where eigen2 types and eigen3 types were both used, but needed to be separated to avoid naming collisions. If you're trying to use tf_conversions with "eigen2_*" types on Electric, you will have problems.

Until a few moments ago when I fixed it, the main links under "Documentation" in both the eigen_conversions wiki page and the tf_conversions wiki page linked to an older version of the API documentation. If you're using electric, most (if not all) core packages should be using eigen3.

The API documentation should be clearer, now.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1